# Swap items in xib on Xcode OS X application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstableview

i'm new to .xib because i always used storyboards while developing iOS app. Now i wanted to taste a bit of OS X but i came up with this problem.
[image]
Let's say i have this view in my xib file, now how can i show different "views" in the right side depending on the selection of the `TableView cells`? What i want to achieve is not a *always-the-same* view filled with different data (Cellular Contacts app and so), i would like to display totally different views.
In iOS i would have used something like SplitViewController setting a Master-Detail dependency and performing different segues, but here? Should i create other .xib files and load them depending on the selection? How would i achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a Tab View with invisible borders, and on each tab place a different view. Then, when the user selects an item from the list you show the appropriate view by setting the TabView's selected index.

Comment: Seems a good workaround :) how do i set invisible borders?programmatically? and can i set invisible (and untouchable) also the `tab-buttons`?

Comment: Ok found command `tabless` :)

Comment: Yes, I believe you can set all those properties in IB. I'm not sure about how to set them programmatically, but I suggest you to take a look at Apple's reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of classes on iOS that don't have OS X equivalents and even more classes on OS X that don't have iOS equivalents. In this case you'll have to write the lot of it yourself.

In my app (https://github.com/abhibeckert/Dux) I have a split view with an empty custom view inside it on the right side.

When I change views, I create a new view (many ways to do this, you could have an Xib for each view type. I don't do that in mine), then remove all sub views from the custom view and add your new subview.

I have a different view for each *row* in the table view, even though they're usually the same type of detail view. This way scroll positions/etc are preserved if you go back to a previously used row.

I'm also using NDocument, which makes my code extremely complicated — as it simply is not designed to be used in a master detail interface. You'll probably want to avoid that.

NSDocument has some features you might want however. For example it has a separate undo stack for each document. It's quite easy for you to implement this.